# Find the set of values for $c\in \mathbb R$ that allows real solution for $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, radicals

> Given $\{x,c\}\subset \mathbb R$, $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+c}~~~~ (1)$.
>
> Find: set of values for $c$ such that $(1)$ has solution in $\mathbb R$.

Question from the Brazilian Math Olympiad 2004. No solution provided.

I'm not sure whether I'm setting the right constraints to find the asked set. Hints and full solutions are appreciated.

**My attempt:** as an initial observation, the solution must consider at least 2 constraints: $(c_1)$ $x\ge 0;$ and, $(c_2)$ $\sqrt{x}\ge -c$, to avoid negative arguments in the square root.

By assuming ($c_1$) and ($c_2$) hold, and squaring both terms in (1) we get
$$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+c}\Leftrightarrow x=\sqrt{x}+c\Leftrightarrow x-c=\sqrt{x}.$$

Now considering an addicional constraint $(c_3)$ $x-c\ge 0$, and squaring both terms, we get
$$x-c=\sqrt{x}\Leftrightarrow x^2-2cx+c^2=x \Leftrightarrow x^2-(2c+1)x+c^2=0$$
To solve this last equation, notice that 
$$\triangle=(2c+1)^2-4c^2=4c+1$$
Therefore, another constraint, for real roots, is $\triangle\ge 0$ or $(c_4)$ $c\ge -1/4$. And the tentative solution for $x$, before checking constraints, will be given by
$$x=\frac{2c+1\pm\sqrt{4c+1}}{2}.$$
Now the set of values for $c$ that leads to a real solution in $x$, will be the set resulting from the intersection of 4 conditions:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
(c_1)~~x\ge 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{2c+1\pm\sqrt{4c+1}}{2}\ge 0\Leftrightarrow 2c+1\ge\pm\sqrt{4c+1}\\ 
(c_2)~~\sqrt{x}\ge -c \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{2c+1\pm\sqrt{4c+1}}{2}}\ge -c\\
(c_3)~~x\ge c\Leftrightarrow \frac{2c+1\pm\sqrt{4c+1}}{2}\ge c\Leftrightarrow 1 \ge \pm\sqrt{4c+1}\Leftrightarrow 1 \ge \sqrt{4c+1}\Leftrightarrow c \le 0\\ 
(c_4)~~c\ge -1/4\\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Question: (a) is this last step the right set of conditions to be intersected to give the asked set for $c$? (b) how to solve for the intersection of the conditions?

Hints and full answers are appreciated. Maybe I'm just complicating something that is a lot easier.

Comment: It seems you need conditions on $c$. So $c_4$ is the information you are looking for.

Comment: You can simplify $c_1$ since $2c+1\ge \sqrt{4c+1}$. Also you got $c_3$ wrong, it should read $x\ge c$. Then I think you can differentiate the cases $c>0$ and $c\le 0$; $c>0$ can simplify quite a bit of conditions

Comment: @user160738 thanks for the hint...you're right... just fixed $c_3$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem ignoring the external square roots, as both are positive values.

Now

$$(\sqrt x)^2-\sqrt x-c=0$$

has real roots only when

$$1+4c\ge0,$$ and these roots are

$$\sqrt x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4c}}{2},$$ one of which is necessarily not smaller than $\dfrac12$.

With

$$c\ge-\frac14$$

both $x$ and $\sqrt x+c$ are guaranteed to be non-negative.

Comment: Why here we don't need another constraint, $c\le 0$, otherwise $\sqrt{x}< 0$... that doesn't make sense. Check that $\sqrt{x}< 0$,  $\forall c> 0$ in the negative sign. Am I missing something? Ahh...  this happens only on the negative sign solution.... no problem in the positive... Ok, i think i understand now...

Comment: By definition $\sqrt z\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slightly different point of view, which may be useful in a different situation. Since it is easier to express $c$ in terms of $x$ rather than the other way around, you might make this argument:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x - \sqrt{x}$. Then
$$\exists x\in \mathbb{R} (x\geq 0 \land c = x - \sqrt{x} = f(x)) \Leftrightarrow c \in {\rm ran} (f)$$
(there is no need for any other conditions because the domain of $f$ is exactly $x \geq 0$). Now here the substitution $\sqrt{x} = t$ would make finding the range more convenient. I will do it by noting that $g:\sqrt{x}\mapsto x$, with domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$, is **surjective** and so ${\rm ran}(g) = {\rm dom}(f)$; not only can the two functions be composed, but also ${\rm ran} (f\circ g) = {\rm ran} (f)$.

So instead of studying the solutions of an equation for some (unspecified) $c$, you could examine the function $f\circ g: \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $f(g(t)) = t^2 - t$. (All the talk about domains and ranges in the previous paragraph was to demonstrate that no additional constraints are needed.) It's a quadratic restricted to $[0, +\infty)$ whose vertex is easily found to be $(1/2, -1/4)$ so the range is $[-1/4, +\infty)$.

This isn't really any different from finding the roots (parametrically) and checking/requiring that at least one be non-negative (as Yves does). But if it had been something more complicated than a quadratic, it is usually easier to find the range than to solve the corresponding equation.

**EDIT:** Note that when solving equations with radicals on both sides, $\sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{g(x)}$, it is redundant to add both $f(x) \geq 0$ and $g(x) \geq 0$. For any solution of the squared equation, $f(x) = g(x)$ they are equivalent. In your approach, $(c_1) \Leftrightarrow (c_2)$. And later on, the second squaring produces $x = (x-c)^2$ which automatically guarantees $(c_1)$. So only $(c_3)$ and $(c_4)$ are left, and it is not hard to check that the latter implies the former, since it is enough for **one** of the roots to meet it (I think you had already figured that out).